# Windows 10 bios questions

Tags: windows-10, bios

How can I bootup Windows 10 without a keyboard and mouse plugged in?  Something in BIOS?

Also, how to enable on powerless, turn back on (when the power comes back on, turn automatically on without pressing the actual power button"?

Lastly, how to disable Windows updates?

I'll be connecting this computer to a router with SIM card for network connection, so I don't want Windows 10 updates to happen.

Comment: Windows boots up without keyboard and mouse afaik. That has nothing got to do with UEFI or BIOS. If the system starts then windows will also start. Turn back on is a UEFI  or BIOS setting. Windows updates cannot be disabled in general, in all versions, but also should not happen if it is not a broadband connection. It think it detects that you are online via sim and does not download anything per default.

Comment: "How can" anyone "bootup Windows 10" period?

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding to the question about the turn on PC when the power come back**
You can just turn on **Restore AC Power Loss** option base on your Bios model. You can check this video for more information
[How to set the device to automatically power on after AC power restoration?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Q5vPI5hIKY)

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. Still waiting for the computer to arrive so I can test

Comment: how do you disable those "press any key to continue" on startup.  For example, I want Windows 10 to boot-up to Windows without any keyboard / mouse interaction.

Comment: You mean that your PC is boot up as normal when power is back, but it required to press any key to continue?

Comment: When do you get this message. It usually only occurs when you want to boot from USB/DVD. If It is because of this reason, You should change to boot priority in bios also.